# How do you set a losing condition on a C++ Game?

Tags: c++, random, numbers, case

/*I tried creating a Guessing Number Game on C++, I went on ahead and make a program that generates a random number ranging from 1 to 1000, and set a winning condition. that is if the user input the random generated number then they won. but i also want to set a losing condition. for example, the user only has 10 tries before the user lose the game. I have a feeling that the answer is quite simple but i simply can't put my head into it.*\

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void tips()
{
    std::cout << "Pay attention to what the system inputs.\n";
    std::cout << "If Too High, Lower you're number base on your latest guess\n";
    std::cout << "If Too Low,  Guess a higher number base on your latest guess\n";
}

void help()
{
    std::cout << "The Instruction of the game is to guess the random generated number from one to a thousand\n";
}

void quit_game()
{
    std::cout << "You have quited the Game\n";
}

void play_game()
{
    int random = rand() % 1001; 
    std::cout << "Guess A Number:\n";
    while(true)
    {
        int guess;
          std::cin >> guess;
         if(guess == random)
        {
            std::cout << "You Are Victorous!\n";
            break;
        } else if (guess < random)
        {
            std::cout << "Too low\n";
        }else
        {
            std::cout << "Too high\n";
        }
    }
}

int main ()
{
  srand(time(NULL));
  int selected;
  do
    {
     std::cout << "0. Quit Game" << std::endl << "1. Play Game\n";
     std::cout << "2. Help" << std::endl << "3. Tips\n";
     std::cin >> selected;

       switch (selected)
       {
        case 0:
           quit_game();
             break;
        case 1:
           play_game();
             break;
        case 2:
           help();
             break;
        case 3:
           tips();
            break;
       
       default:
           std::cout << "You have entered an invalid option\n";
       }
    }

  while (selected != 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `while(true)` you can just use a for loop:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void tips()
{
    std::cout << "Pay attention to what the system inputs.\n";
    std::cout << "If Too High, Lower you're number base on your latest guess\n";
    std::cout << "If Too Low,  Guess a higher number base on your latest guess\n";
}

void help()
{
    std::cout << "The Instruction of the game is to guess the random generated number from one to a thousand\n";
}

void quit_game()
{
    std::cout << "You have quited the Game\n";
}

void play_game(std::size_t max_guesses)
{
    int random = rand() % 1001; 
    std::cout << "Guess A Number:\n";
    for(std::size_t i=0;i<max_guesses;++i)
    {
        int guess;
          std::cin >> guess;
        if(guess == random)
        {
            std::cout << "You Are Victorous!\n";
            return;
        } else if (guess < random)
        {
            std::cout << "Too low\n";
        }else
        {
            std::cout << "Too high\n";
        }
    }

    std::cout << "You Lost!\n";
    return;
}

int main ()
{
  srand(time(NULL));
  constexpr std::size_t num_guesses=5;
  int selected;
  do
    {
     std::cout << "0. Quit Game" << std::endl << "1. Play Game\n";
     std::cout << "2. Help" << std::endl << "3. Tips\n";
     std::cin >> selected;

       switch (selected)
       {
        case 0:
           quit_game();
             break;
        case 1:
            play_game(num_guesses);
             break;
        case 2:
           help();
             break;
        case 3:
           tips();
            break;
       
       default:
           std::cout << "You have entered an invalid option\n";
       }
    }

  while (selected != 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use another variable in your play_game function to keep track of how many tries the player's had.

```
void play_game()
{
    static const int MAX_GUESSES = 10; // You can change this
    int number_of_guesses = 0;

    int random = rand() % 1001; 
    std::cout << "Guess A Number:\n";
    while(true)
    {
        int guess;
          std::cin >> guess;
         if(guess == random)
        {
            std::cout << "You Are Victorous!\n";
            break;
        } else if (guess < random)
        {
            std::cout << "Too low\n";
        }else
        {
            std::cout << "Too high\n";
        }

        ++number_of_guesses;
        if (number_of_guesses == MAX_GUESSES)
        {
            std::cerr << "Too many guesses!" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need use a global variable as maximum number of try and another variable that count user play.

```
const unsigned Maximum_try = 10;

void play_game()
{
    static unsigned number_of_play = 0;
    int random = rand() % 1001;
    std::cout << "Guess A Number:\n";
    while (true)
    {
        int guess;
        std::cin >> guess;
        number_of_play++;
        if (guess == random)
        {
            std::cout << "You Are Victorous!\n";
            break;
        }
        else if (guess < random)
        {
            std::cout << "Too low\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Too high\n";
        }

        if (number_of_play == Maximum_try)
        {
            std::cout << "The answer was: " << random << std::endl;
            std::cout << "YOU LOSE! Try again dear :-)\n";
            number_of_play = 0; 
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Avoid global when possible, and it is here.